# Разная работа похожих одиннаковых массивов

Tags: python-3.x, словари

Попробовал создать массив из N словарей с помощью двух способов, в обоих массив выглядит одиннаково, но работает по-разному. В первом способе какой бы индекс и ключ:значение не задать, пара ключ:значение будет появляться во всех словарях. Второй работает так, как и ожидалось

[image: пример кода]

Comment: Получается а это массив из 9-ти ссылок на один и тот же словарь, или как?

Comment: Да, проверил. Эта механика создания массива создаёт N ссылок